# $\exists$="Exists" gives Ёxist" (E with dots)

Tags: overleaf

My code is:

```
$\exists$="Exists" \\
```

is gives me

```
*exists sign*Ёxist"
```

In other words E with 2 dots and also `=` disappeared. I couldn't replicate this error in the new document. I took the template from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/tim-st/latex-cheatsheet). `$\exists$=\"Exists"` didn't help. I'm doing it on overleaf with the default settings. What could be the reason?

Comment: This is unrelated to your overleaf tag.  In code you have not shown you have presumably loaded a language shortcut eg babel german such that `"E` is short for `\"{E}`

Comment: you should almost never use `"` in tex use `\`\`` and `''`

Comment: as guessed the tex document you link to has `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`

Comment: To add to what @DavidCarlisle said re: (not) using `"`, the `csquotes` package also provides a high-level interface to quotes. Worth looking into!

Comment: Thanks! I removed `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` and the problem is solved

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...